# Why can't I see Express runs on port 3000 when I check http://my.server.ip:3000?

Tags: node.js, server, localhost, pm2, ssh-tunnel

I have installed NodeJS on my remote server and uploaded an image on it. If I connect to the server through a tunnel SSH that ports `localhost:3000` of the remote server to the `localhost:3030`, I can see my image on `http://localhost:3030/images/static/footer.jpeg` but when I try `http://server.ip.address:3000/images/static/footer.jpeg` it doesn't work!

I also can see express welcome message on `http://localhost:3030` but can't see it on `http://server.ip.address:3000`.

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably because you’re redirecting it to localhost. That’s not visible from outside. Make sure it’s redirected to an outward open port.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: What file should I check to see and correct? If it's helpful let me know what files I can attach to my question?